# How to convert NSData to a readable format JSON/text in python

Tags: python, ios, json, text, nsdata

I'm trying to convert data received from iOS application into readable format. Here is the sample of the data I have:

```
`[(b'\x04\x0bstreamtyped\x81\xe8\x03\x84\x01@\x84\x84\x84\x08NSString\x01\x84\x84 \x08NSObject\x00\x85\x84\x01+(84d8bd7bde803cb4b0ff07a918513c0fb0b92a2f\x86',), ( b'\x04\x0bstreamtyped\x81\xe8\x03\x84\x01@\x84\x84\x84\x08NSNumber\x00\x84\x84\x 07NSValue\x00\x84\x84\x08NSObject\x00\x85\x84\x01*\x84\x84\x01q\x97\x82\xd7\xd9\ x11\x00\x86',), (b'\x04\x0bstreamtyped\x81\xe8\x03\x84\x01@\x84\x84\x84\x07NSArr ay\x00\x84\x84\x08NSObject\x00\x85\x84\x01i\x00\x86',), (b'\x04\x0bstreamtyped\x 81\xe8\x03\x84\x01@\x84\x84\x84\x08NSString\x01\x84\x84\x08NSObject\x00\x85\x84\ x01+\x1acom.bohemiancoding.sketch3\x86',), (b'\x04\x0bstreamtyped\x81\xe8\x03\x8 4\x01@\x84\x84\x84\x08NSNumber\x00\x84\x84\x07NSValue\x00\x84\x84\x08NSObject\x0 0\x85\x84\x01*\x84\x84\x01q\x97\x81(/\x86',), (b'\x04\x0bstreamtyped\x81\xe8\x03 \x84\x01@\x84\x84\x84\x08NSNumber\x00\x84\x84\x07NSValue\x00\x84\x84\x08NSObject \x00\x85\x84\x01*\x84\x84\x01q\x977\x86',), (b'\x04\x0bstreamtyped\x81\xe8\x03\x 84\x01@\x84\x84\x84\x08NSString\x01\x84\x84\x08NSObject\x00\x85\x84\x01+\x08APPS TORE\x86',)]`
```

Is it possible to convert this to a readable format using python? I have been searching on forums and SO.com itself for some info on how to perform this conversion in python.

Comment: This looks like [NeXT/Apple typedstream binary data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834352/inspecting-files-of-type-next-apple-typedstream-version-4-nsarchiver).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Hi, I have updated the question. Please take a look. I am new to stackoverflow so let me know if the question still needs to updated.

Comment: It's a little broad still, and doesn't show *what you found* when you searched. I found the name of the format at least, which should give you something more to search on combined with the word Python, for example. Unfortunately, the Python package index is down at this time so I can't see if a lead I found would help you at all.